# Creating a custom method using @link() wihout having to pass in look up field

Tags: django, routes, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an API end point that returns the current Screener.
A Screener is a one-to-one model with a user. I would like to hit this end point and have all the necessary info returned, however, I would like it to return with out passing any params.
Right now when using the @link() decorator the url becomes screener/{look-up-field}/current.
I would like it not have the look up field in the url. 
My viewset:

```
class ScreenerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Screener
    serializer_class = ScreenerSerializer
    permission_classes = (ObjectPermissions,)
    queryset = Screener.objects.all()

    @link()
    def current(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        screener = get_object_or_404(Screener, user__id=request.user.id)
        data = self.serializer_class(screener)
        return Response(data=data.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My routes:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/screener', ScreenerViewSet)
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default DRF `@link` decorator only works on the detail-level.

For collection-level `@link` and `@action` decorators you can use [drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions), which provides these.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove *args and **kwargs from the method definition? I this is the solution but right now I can not test it.

Comment: Nope, not the solution :(

Comment: Can you wire your custom view method in a normal urlpattern? Like explained here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly